# SSRS Count Distinct with iif filter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

So this is a pretty complex one.  I am trying to put a filter on a count distinct in SSRS.  Here is the situation.

I have 3 datasets in the report.  All 3 datasets have the same fields but are built on different code.

I want to count the distinct hospitals in one of the datasets while applying a filter to one of the fields.

For example I want to Count distinct Hospital codes when the DatePeriod is between 3 months ago and today.  Here is what I have.

```
=iif((Fields!DatePeriod.Value, "Rpt_WinBack") between DateAdd("m",-3,Today()) and DateAdd("m",0,Today()), (CountDistinct(Fields!HospCode.Value, "Rpt_WinBack") & " Hospitals"),nothing)
```

I currently get an error that states:

"Textbox4 refers directly to the field 'DatePeriod' without specifying a dataset aggregate.  When the report contains multiple datasets, filed references outside of a data region must be contained within aggregate functions which specify a dataset scope."

It is possible that a hospital will show up on multiple dates.

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
=CountDistinct(iif((Fields!DatePeriod.Value, "Rpt_WinBack") between DateAdd("m",-3,Today()) and DateAdd("m",0,Today()), (Fields!HospCode.Value, "Rpt_WinBack"),nothing )) & " Hospitals"
```

Comment: Thanks but no joy:  "The Value expression for the text box 'Textbox4' uses an aggregate expression without a scope.  A scope is required for all aggregates used outside of a data region unless the report contains exactly one dataset."

Not sure why- the scope does call out the individual dataset "rpt_WinBack"  Will keep looking.  Found a workaround, just not the best solution.  I filter the data when comes into the report- trouble is, I want to compare last years data with this years.

Comment: It might be best to do this in your query, add a column with a case statement that resolves to a 1 or a 0 and then just sum that column for your final number.

Comment: I might have to do that, was just trying to leave some flexibility built into it.  Meaning if the user changes the time period on the report it will change.  Unfortunately nothing is perfect, so do what we have to do.

Comment: If you continue to attempt inside the RDL, BarneyL is correct, you will always need to perform the aggregate on the result of your IIF().  IE: COUNT(IIF()), SUM(IIF()) you cannot have SSRS attempt an aggregate as one of the results of the expression.